# conditional modification of data in complex mysql(mariadb) table according to time lapse

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb

First, I'm sorry for poor english.

```
MariaDB []> desc articles;
+ ------------ + ------------------ + ------ + ----- + ---- ----- + ---------------- +
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+ ------------ + ------------------ + ------ + ----- + ---- ----- + ---------------- +
| id | int (10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| user_id | int (10) unsigned | NO | MUL | NULL | |
| title | varchar (191) | NO | MUL | NULL | |
| content | text | NO | | NULL | |
| created_at | timestamp | YES | | NULL | |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES | | NULL | |
| limit_count | int (11) | NO | | 0 | |
+ ------------ + ------------------ + ------ + ----- + ---- ----- + ---------------- +
```

There are many posts in articles.
I want to increase the 'limit_count' of each post in mariadb by the elapsed time(current time - create_at) of each post.

I have tried the following, but I do not think it is complete.

```
UPDATE articles
    SET limit_count = limit_count + ((NOW () - created_at) * 10)
    WHERE exists (select * from articles where limit_count> 0);
```

How can I code this to work?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** greatly simplify the `WHERE` clause to

```
    WHERE limit_count> 0
```

** you can't do arithmetic directly with `NOW()`.  Instead of `NOW () - created_at`, perhaps you want

```
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - created_at
```